# Issues with key in React map

Tags: reactjs, key, jsx

I am trying to generate unique key while iterating over map by appending label name with index.

please find the below snippet.

````
const controls = [
  { label: "Salad", type: "salad" },
  { label: "Bacon", type: "bacon" },
  { label: "Cheese", type: "cheese" },
  { label: "Meat", type: "meat" }
];

const BuildControls = props => (
  <div className="BuildControls">
    {controls.map((item, index) => (
      <BuildControl
        ```key={item.label + index}```
        label={item.label}
        added={() => props.ingredientsAdded(item.type)}
        removed={() => props.ingredientsRemoved(item.type)}
        disabled={props.disabled[item.type]}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
````

I am getting following error when i am trying to add items repeatedly.

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
>       in div (created by burgers)
>       in burgers (created by BurgerBuilder)
>       in Aux (created by BurgerBuilder)
>       in BurgerBuilder (created by App)
>       in div (created by App)
>       in App

Comment: Are you sure that `BuildControls` is the source of the problem here? I don't see that component anywhere in your stack trace. What does your `BurgerBuilder` code look like? Edit: I would also get rid of the `+ index` part of the `key` value. The value of `key` should be the same, even if the items are reordered. However if you reordered your `controls` array the keys would all be different and throw it off. Just use `item.label` as the key.

Comment: How about <BuildControl
     key={item.label + index}
        label={item.label}
        added={() => props.ingredientsAdded(item.type)}
        removed={() => props.ingredientsRemoved(item.type)}
        disabled={props.disabled[item.type]}
      />

Comment: Also please post full code/ fiddle link so we can debug

Comment: I have added my work in https://codesandbox.io/s/building-a-burger-xxoge. please check and let me know what should be added in BuildControl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually simple,

```
{controls.map((item, index) => (
   <BuildControl
      key={`${item.label}${index}`}
      label={item.label}
      added={() => props.ingredientsAdded(item.type)}
      removed={() => props.ingredientsRemoved(item.type)}
      disabled={props.disabled[item.type]}
   />
))}
```

---

**Update**

The warning is from your `Burgers.js` file, you are creating repeated `key`, do this,

```
<BurgerIngredient key={`${item}${i}`} type={item} />
```

Comment: It's not working. please check the problem code     https://codesandbox.io/s/building-a-burger-xxoge

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what the problem is because if you look at this snippet it does not give any error. Not sure what logic is in your `BuildControl` component.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


const controls = [{
   label: "Salad",
   type: "salad"
  },
  {
   label: "Bacon",
   type: "bacon"
  },
  {
   label: "Cheese",
   type: "cheese"
  },
  {
  label: "Meat",
  type: "meat"
  }
  ];


function BuildControl(props) {
  return ( <h1> {props.data.type} </h1>)}

function App() {
  return ( <div className = "BuildControls" > {
     controls.map((item, index) => (<BuildControl data = {item}/>))
   } </div>
 );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , rootElement);
```

Comment: There is no issue with passing the data, but the key itself. OP need to set a unique key because he did not have unique value in `controls` array.

Comment: Yeah you are right the syntax which he has written it wrong it should be 
key={`${item.label}${index}`}

Comment: After replacing this also no use.